# Node JS Wrong Value Count On Row when inserting to database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, rest

I am attempting to upload some information to my database, particularly this is the JSON request I am sending to my database. I am using a MYSQL instance

```
  {
    "doctor_public_address":"0x34916740ed6e957e1d6f34eF60225685dBf5ca5f",
    "drug_name":"Oxycytocin",
    "drug_manufacturer":"GlaxoSmithKline",
    "patient_age":22,
    "practice_id":"4532ADRC41Z",
    "drug_dosage":"1500mg",
    "drug_frequency":"15ml every 12 hours",
    "doctor_name":"Amgad",
    "doctor_license_number":"531ACDEF5GH",
    "patient_address":"0x5E31D7dB70Ffb0af8b7740a5EBa19717165ce5B1"
}
```

This is my node.js endpoint

```
    app.post("/prescribe-patient",(req,res)=>{
    console.log("Prescribing prescription to patient")
    console.log("The request is", req.body.doctor_public_address)
    db.query("INSERT into prescription (doctor_public_address,drug_name,drug_manufacturer,patient_age,practice_id,drug_dosage,drug_frequency,doctor_name,doctor_license_number,patient_address) VALUES (?)",[req.body.doctor_public_address,req.body.drug_name,req.body.drug_manufacturer, req.body.patient_age,req.body.practice_id,req.body.drug_dosage,req.body.drug_frequency,req.body.doctor_name,req.body.doctor_license_number,req.body.patient_address],(err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        }else{
            res.send(result)
        }
    })
})
```

This is the schema of the table I am uploading data to

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGqVO.png)

Finally this is the error i am receiving

```
    {
    "code": "ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW",
    "errno": 1136,
    "sqlMessage": "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",
    "sqlState": "21S01",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "INSERT into prescription (doctor_public_address,drug_name,drug_manufacturer,patient_age,practice_id,drug_dosage,drug_frequency,doctor_name,doctor_license_number,patient_address) VALUES ('0x34916740ed6e957e1d6f34eF60225685dBf5ca5f')"
}
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Hey @Khandkar Islam in the INSERT statament, you need to specify a field, you are passing 10 and the are 9.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying, I am passing 10 data objects to 10 fields, in my json and code?

Comment: The problem is that you have missing data to pass. You are missing the fields `created_date` and `prescription_number`. Even if you don't want to pass them anything, pass them a NULL or a model date, in the case of date.